# When user enters specific String, event is called

Tags: c#, html

I am building a 'fake' web browser in C#. It still uses the IE browser module from Visual Studio, but as opposed to online web pages being displayed in the module, I am designing it to only display local HTML files. So far i have a 'click' event that displays a single, local HTML file in the browser module when a button is clicked.

Below is working 'click' event:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    this.webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(String.Format("file:///{0}/post-op/index.html", curDir));
}
```

I plan on having a textbox or combobox (whatever is more convenient) where the user can type in a fake 'web address' (something like www.post-op.com) and press enter. The program will then read the string and find the local HTML index file that corresponds to that string being entered (i.e. "file:///{0}/post-op/index.html").

Comment: thanks @CodeCaster I've updated the description to hopefully give more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you could use a dictionary to store the keywords and the filename belonging to that keyword:

```
var filemapping = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "pre-op", "file:///{0}/pre-op/index.html" },
    { "post-op", "file:///{0}/post-op/index.html" },
    ...
};
```

Then when the user enters text or clicks a button, you look up the filename belonging to the entered keyword:

```
var textEntered = textBox1.Text;

string filename;
if (filemapping.TryGetValue(textEntered, out filename))
{
    string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    var uri = new Uri(String.Format(filename, curDir));
    webBrowser1.Navigate(uri);
}
```

Added benefit of the dictionary approach is that you can provide autocomplete data or a dropdown list based on `filemapping.Keys`.

Comment: Thanks @CodeCaster This is really helpful. A few questions: should this all be wrapped in its own class then called when I make events for pressing enter and/or clicking a 'search' button. Also, is the code i had previously useless in this situation? it seems like the NavigateTo is not being recognized as a function...

Comment: Whether you put it in its own class does not matter for the functionality. I have updated my answer to look more like your code.

Comment: Perfect! Everything was working except the path to the file, was having trouble finding where to place the existing code. All fixed now. Thank you for your patience.